# Null argument error on MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy

I am getting the following error - code “Error:  The ‘Connection String’ argument cannot be null or empty.” when running the MSDeploy.  When I examined the SetParameters.xml file I noticed the following parameter settings.

```
<setParameter name="ApplicationServices-Deployment Connection String" value="" /> 
<setParameter name="MusicStoreEntities-Deployment Connection String" value="" />
```

I am not the one who developed this package and I am not sure what the arguments should be.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you are not providing a value for the destination connection string for a database, even though you are deploying it to a remote server.

1. Double-click Properties for your WAP
2. Click Package/Publish SQL
3. Click a database in Database Entries
4. Scroll down and provide a valid connection string in Database Entry Details > Connection string for destination database