# Publish Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, msbuild, connection-string, publish, azure-webjobs

When I try to publish Azure WebJob I got an error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4283,5):
>   Error : The
>   'WebJobArchivingExpiredRequest.PixlocateEntities-Web.config Connection
>   String' argument cannot be null or empty.

but I have the following line in app.config/connectionStrings :

```
<add name="PixlocateEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:[myserver].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=PixlocateDev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[username];Password=[password]&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

also, I have 2 connection strings in web.config:

```
<add name="PixlocateEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:[myserver].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=PixlocateDev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[username];Password=[password]&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="WebJobArchivingExpiredRequest.PixlocateEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:[myserver].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=PixlocateDev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[username];Password=[password]&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

why it happens and how to fix?

Comment: I think the error is talking about your `Web.config` file

Comment: I have the same connectionString in Web.Config

Answer (score 0):

In the Publish wizard, under Settings >> Databases, uncheck "Use this connection string at runtime".

Comment: I want to update web.config connection string on server (want to have different connection strings for my local and remote), so, can't uncheck it

Comment: Use a config transform.  You don't need to use the wizard for that.

Comment: it helped me to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792308/null-argument-error-on-msdeploy .